# Make a plasmoid cover the whole screen

Tags: kde, kde-4, kde-plasma-workspace

I'd like my KDE4 desktop to be filled with nothing but a view of the Desktop files, like the KDE3 one (or really, any other desktop). How can I resize the *Desktop folder view* plasmoid to take up the whole desktop screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>[Joke start]</sub>
To resize the Desktop folder view plasmoid to take up the whole desktop screen you can... resize it to take up the whole desktop screen.
<sup>[Joke end]</sup>

But a much better solution is this:

- Right click the desktop and select *Desktop Settings*
- Change *Layout* to *Folder View*
- Press Apply

Your desktop is now entirely a *Folder View* widget.
*Location*, *Display* and *Filter* sections of *Desktop Settings* (which are now renamed to *Folder View Settings*) contain the same settings as a normal *Folder View* widget settings.

This works in KDE 4.7, but I don't remember such setting in 4.6, so I think it is not there.

Comment: Works fine in 4.6.5.